# Creating aligned columns for variables that change

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, text-alignment

So I've managed to align several variables/text using padding. However, my code involves changing variables inside a list, and therefore this changes the length, and affects the alignment of my columns.

```
product_names = ["hamburger", "cheeseburger", "small fries"]
product_costs = [0.99, 1.29, 1.49]
product_quantity = [10,5,20]

print(format("Product",'<10s'),"Price","Quantity",sep = '\t')

        for x in range(len(product_names)):
            print(format(product_names[x],'<16s'),end ='')

            print(product_costs[x],product_quantity[x],sep = '\t')
```

the output I get is :

```
Product     Price   Quantity
hamburger       0.99    10
cheeseburger    1.29    5
small fries     1.49    20
```

but if I change cheeseburger to something longer. for instance double cheeseburger. Ill get.

```
Product     Price   Quantity
hamburger       0.99    10
double cheeseburger1.29 5
small fries     1.49    20
```

how do I keep my columns consistent?

Comment: You have to come with a good guess or get the longest name and use that

Answer (score 1):

Either allocate more space for the text or truncate the text:

```
def truncate(s): 
    if len(s) >= 16: 
        return s[:13] + '...'
    else:
        return s

print(format(truncate(product_names[x]),'<16s'),end ='')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that prints a table using the column inputs to determine the width of each column.  It works by using a default string that gets replicated for the number of columns; it is then formatted to have a string format with the width of the max characters of each column plus the gap.  That string is then formatted with each row to print the line.

If a `header` list is supplied it will adjust the width accordingly and print that as well.  The `gap` indicates how many spaces between each column.

```
def table_printer(*columns, header=None, gap=1):
    print_header = False
    if header is None:
        header = ['']*len(columns)
    else:
        assert len(header)==len(columns), (
            "Must have same number of headers as columns."
            )
        print_header = True

    col_widths = [max(map(len, map(str, c+[h])))+gap for c,h in zip(columns, header)]
    width_formatter = '{{:<{}}}'*len(columns)
    row_formatter = width_formatter.format(*col_widths)

    if print_header:
        print(row_formatter.format(*header))
    for row in zip(*columns):
        print(row_formatter.format(*row))


product_names = ["hamburger", "cheeseburger", "small fries"]
product_costs = [0.99, 1.29, 1.49]
product_quantity = [10,5,20]

table_printer(product_names, product_costs, product_quantity, 
              header=['Product', 'Price', 'Quantity'], 
              gap=3)

# prints:
Product        Price   Quantity
hamburger      0.99    10
cheeseburger   1.29    5
small fries    1.49    20
```